# How to distinguish two kinds of similar functions or methods in Python?

Tags: python, function

In python, I have two kinds of functions or methods with different type of input arguments, for example

```
def fp(ps):
    print(ps, "ps should be a cartesian points array")

def fb(bs):
    print(bs, "bs should be a barycentric points array")
```

I will pass one or more above functin objects to another function, for example:

```
def process(f0, f1):
    print("I want to call `f0` and `f1`!")
    print(" `f0(ps)` or `f0(bs)`?")
    print(" `f1(ps)` or `f1(bs)`?")
```

Whether there is a concise way to decide what parameters ( `ps` or `bs`) I should pass in to call `f0` and `f1`.

Comment: If both are arrays and cannot be distinguished by their type, it's not possible. A human has to do it.

Comment: `process` should define that as part of its interface. E.g. "`f0` needs to be a *callable* which accepts a points array as argument." The caller of `process` needs to adhere to the interface, it's not `process`'s job to figure that out dynamically.

Comment: In my application, `process`  will do the same thing for these two kind of functions after call them. Of course, I can add more parameters to tell `process` what kind call I want, but which will make the interface of `process` too complex.

Comment: No, don't add more parameters. Just define what each parameter *is*. It can either be *a callable accepting an array of point values*, or *a callable accepting an array of barycenters*. Think of those as *types*. "Callable that accepts an array of points" is a type just like `str` or `int` is. You wouldn't let a function accept random types and then figure out what to do with them; the function *defines* what types it expects.

Comment: Im my application, maybe I will pass three or more such functions to `process`, and handling the calls to these functions can be very cumbersome.

Comment: I don't understand the difficulty. `process` must define *"I will call whatever callback you pass as `f0` with an array of point values"*. Period. Every other thing that accepts callbacks does that. E.g. in `list.sort(key=...)`, the `key` callback *will be passed one element from the list and must return a comparable value.* It's the function that accepts the callback that sets the contract, not vice versa.

Comment: the returns for `fp` and `fb` are same kind things.  I will try to make my question more clear. Thanks for your discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Python decorators can solve my problem, just like following:

```
from functools import wraps

def cartesian(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def add_attribute(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    add_attribute.__dict__['coordtype'] = 'cartesian' 
    return add_attribute 

def barycentric(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def add_attribute(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    add_attribute.__dict__['coordtype'] = 'barycentric' 
    return add_attribute 

@cartesian
def fp(ps):
    print('This function need a cartesian type input!')

@barycentric
def fb(bs):
    print('This function need a barycentric type input!')

def process(f0, f1):
    bs = ...
    ps = ...
    if f0.coordtype == 'cartesian':
        val0 = f0(ps)
    elif f0.coordtype == 'barycentric':
        val0 = f0(bs)

    if f1.coordtype == 'cartesian':
        val1 = f1(ps)
    elif f1.coordtype == 'barycentric':
        val1 = f1(bs)
    ... # do something for val0 and val1
```

Then I just need one implement for `process` with a simple interface.